# What is the best way to provide "search as you type"?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

I'm porting a Forms app to a VB.NET web app, and one of the feature the users really liked was the ability to narrow the possible choices as the user typed in a search box. The search itself goes against multiple tables and columns (and takes several seconds), so it's not a simple AutoComplete or anything. What's the best way to allow the user to type, and asynchronously update a ListView with the matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery will be a good solution to filter the ListView at client side. Check this recent [article](http://beckelman.net/post/2008/10/16/Client-Side-ASPNET-ListView-Sorting-via-jQuery-TableSorter-Plugin-Demo.aspx)  and another cool [demo here](http://beckelman.net/post/2008/11/20/jQuery-tableSorter-and-quickSearch-Plugins-Together-Demo.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [Dynamic Populate](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/DynamicPopulate/DynamicPopulate.aspx) control in the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/) to do most of the legwork.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I can't get the Dynamic Populate control to fire as the user types, only when something is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ASP.NET AJAX controls. There is a specific control for autocompletion:

> AutoComplete is an ASP.NET AJAX
>   extender that can be attached to any
>   TextBox control, and will associate
>   that control with a popup panel to
>   display words that begin with the
>   prefix typed into the textbox.
>
> The dropdown with candidate words
>   supplied by a web service is
>   positioned on the bottom left of the
>   text box.
>
> In the sample above, the textbox is
>   associated with an
>   AutoCompleteExtender that pulls words
>   that start with the contents of the
>   textbox using a web service.
>
> When you have typed more content than
>   the specified minimum word length, a
>   popup will show words or phrases
>   starting with that value. Caching is
>   turned on, so typing the same prefix
>   multiple times results in only one
>   call to the web service.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

There is also a control for searching lists, as you described.